# Android:When to refresh data from server

Tags: android

I am building a news application which requires refreshing data from server. Whenever the application is resumed (after a certain time period) I want to refresh the data again and pull in 'newer' news. Is onResume the answer. What is the best way of acheiving this? Can I put a check that data should only be updated when user comes back to activity after a certain amount of time and not always.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to not use the "pull" pattern, because it means the device will wake up to do the polling.  If you let the user choose when to poll the data they may miss important items as well.

My suggestion is to use a "push" pattern using [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) as that will be more battery efficient for the users and reduces the burden on your own servers as there would be less unnecessary polling.

Answer (score 2):

pulling new data on application resume is one way or you can request a data on application launch ... IMO best approach is to let user choose when to update data, such as swiping down from screen to update news.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SharedPreference to store the refresh timestamp each time. Check the interval when you need to refresh.

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    long lastRefresh = sp.getLong("refresh", 0);
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (lastRefresh == 0 || now - lastRefresh > INTERVAL) {
        refresh();
        sp.edit().putLong("refresh", now).commit();
    }
}
```